# How do I describe a partition determined by $R$ by listing pieces?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

$R$ is the relation $\{(1,1),(2,3),(2,2),(3,2),(3,3)\}$ on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. It then is reflexive, symmetric, transitive and thus an equivalence relation. How do I describe the partition formed by $R$ by listing the pieces in the partition?

Comment: By "pieces", do you mean the equivalence classes given by the equivalence relation?

Comment: The pieces would have to be in the partition of the set, so I would guess that an equivalence class would not be one (since R can't be in {1, 2, 3}). I would then guess that the partition would be {{1}, {2}, {3}}, but I am not sure if R would then be a possible relation.

Comment: I'm really unable to comprehend your last comment. Do you have a reference you can cite for the definition you are using of "pieces of a partition", either from your textbook or your class notes?

Comment: My textbook states that given a collection {{1},{2},{3}}, a piece would be {1}. Given this I think that {1} and {2, 3} would be the pieces that make up the partition, but I am not sure.

Comment: The collection $\{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$ is obtained after placing an equivalence relation, if my guess is correct? To be precise, after placing the equivalence relation $i \sim j \iff i = j$ on the set $\{ 1,2,3 \}$. Can you confirm if this is what your notes say?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if that is a collection which satisfies R. The equivalence relation you stated indeed forms that collection.

Comment: Then, by "pieces" your textbook refers to the equivalence classes only. And you are right that (a) this collection does not work for your question, and that (b) the collection $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 2,3 \}$ does work.

Comment: Let me add an answer elaborating this. You can accept it if it satisfies your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pieces of the partition" that arise from an equivalence relation $R$ given on a set are usually called the **equivalence classes**. To describe an equivalence class of an equivalence relation $R$, it is enough to specify any one member of the equivalence class.

---

For your question, there are two equivalence classes, namely,
$$
\{ 1 \} \text{ and } \{ 2, 3 \}.
$$

An equivalence class is usually denoted using box brackets, $[\cdot]$. So, one can list the partition of $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ under the given equivalence relation $R$ as
$$
[1] \text{ and } [2]
$$
or
$$
[1] \text{ and } [3].
$$
To elaborate, if $R$ is an equivalence relation on a set $S$, then for each $x \in S$, the notation $[x]$ is defined as follows:
$$
[x] = \{ y \in S : xRy \}.
$$

---

Note that the equivalence classes will change as your equivalence relation changes. Based on the discussion in the comments, it appears that you were uncertain whether the partition
$$
[1],[2],[3]
$$
would work as an answer to the current question. It does not, because they describe a partition arising from a different equivalence relation on the set $\{ 1,2,3\}$, namely
$$
xRy \iff x = y.
$$